# "Enlarge" 2 different elements in the same position

Tags: html, css

actually i'm working on this element http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/

I'm starting from a free CSS and HTML template, what i need is:

1. "Enlarge" the centered "button" and the list elements (navigation). **I  Need 800x800px for it.**
2. Set a background picture for the centered button

How can i do both things?

Thanks a lot in advice

Edit:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Top Navigation -->

        <header>
        </header>
        <div class="component">

            <!-- Start Nav Structure -->
            <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">Click</button>
            <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>07.45 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>07.55 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>08.15 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>08.17 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>10.47 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>13.20Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>16.30 Uhr</span></a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End of Nav Structure -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="js/demo2.js"></script>
    <!-- For the demo ad only -->
```

Comment: can you post the code you've already written, and/or a fiddle?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jesse added the HTML

Comment: Install Firebug/Use Chrome Devtools and play with the CSS code. It will be a fun thing to do.